# Error connecting to MySql database with SQLalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, linux, sqlalchemy

I am giving it a last try before I give up, I have googling everywhere but still havent found a solution to my error.

Just so clarify some things:

- MySql server IS UP and running
- I am running and PHP admin panel together with mysql in the same server(confirming once again that the mysql server works)
- The connection to the server is TCP
- When i run this python script locally on my windows machine with XAMPP, it works as it should.

When i create docker image and run it, i get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2002, "Can't con                    nect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

So here is my "main.py" file:

```
    from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://myUser:myPassword@MyIpAdress/just_a_test'



db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)
api = Api(app)




#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class exercise(db.Model):
    exerciseId = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    exerciseName = db.Column(db.String(50))
    repetitions = db.Column(db.Integer())
    timeTakenToCompleteRepetitions = db.Column(db.Integer())



class exerciseSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = exercise


exercise_schema = exerciseSchema()
exercises_schema = exerciseSchema(many=True)


class exerciseListResource(Resource):

    def get(self):
        exercise = exercise.query.all()
        return exercises_schema.dump(exercise)

    def post(self):
        new_exercise = exercise(
            exerciseId=request.json['exerciseId'],
            exerciseName=request.json['exerciseName'],
            repetitions=request.json['repetitions'],
            timeTakenToCompleteRepetitions=request.json['timeTakenToCompleteRepetitions']
        )
        db.session.add(new_exercise)
        db.session.commit()
        return_data = exercise_schema.dump(new_exercise)
        return return_data, 201



class exerciseResource(Resource):
    def get(self, exercise_exerciseId):
        exercise = exercise.query.get_or_404(exercise_exerciseId)
        return exercise_schema.dump(exercise)

    def patch(self, exercise_exerciseId):
        exercise = exercise.query.get_or_404(exercise_exerciseId)

        if request.json.get('exerciseName'):
            exercise.exerciseName = request.json['exerciseName']
        if request.json.get('repetitions'):
            exercise.repetitions = request.json['repetitions']
        if request.json.get('timeTakenToCompleteRepetitions'):
            exercise.timeTakenToCompleteRepetitions = request.json['timeTakenToCompleteRepetitions']

        db.session.commit()
        return exercise_schema.dump(exercise)

    def delete(self, exercise_exerciseId):
        exercise = exercise.query.get_or_404(exercise_exerciseId)
        db.session.delete(exercise)
        db.session.commit()
        return '', 204


api.add_resource(exerciseListResource, '/exercise')
api.add_resource(exerciseResource, '/exercise/<int:exercise_exerciseId>')
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

Need to expose the Mysql port via Docker's [`-p` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) like so:

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql-server -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:latest
```

Also, if connecting to local, use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` so the connection is made via tcp instead of local socket file.

Comment: so i should add your line in addition to this:

`-docker run -d -p 5000:8000 --restart always --name my_first_docker_running the_docker_project` ?

And yes, I also tried with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost but that didnt work either.

Comment: Anyways, if i type this: `docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql-server -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:latest`



I get error message: `docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/mysql-server" is already in use by container "1870f47bdccdaa67ae2858e3181b45ed0071edc979ee11caeb378a113006bfbc". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'docker run --help'.
`

Comment: You'll need to remove the old container named `mysql-server` if you use the same name. Where are you running the Python code and MySQL?

Comment: Both the python code and the MySQL are running on the same server.